# How to display animated GIF while React components are rendering

Tags: reactjs, animation, rendering, animated-gif

I have a project where thousands of small pure React components (cells of a giant table) are rendered.
While they are being rendered I'd like to show a loader (animated gif).
I place it directly to html as a background image of `div`

```
<div class="loader"></div>
<div id="react-app-root"></div>
```

with the following styles for `loader`:

```
.loader {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url('./media/loader.gif') no-repeat center;
}
```

when the page starts to render – I see the loader, but it is not animated.
As soon as all React components are rendered – gif's animation starts.

Could please anyone advise how to show animated GIF while components of the application are rendered?